# GroupBy in adapter

Tags: kotlin, group-by, adapter

I'm trying to work with group By and I can't, my intention is to group the companies within the *poblacion. How can I group so that within poblacion it shows me the companies?
it only shows me a repeated item

val works is the list that I receive from the fragment, and what I want is that in the same CardView it shows me the companies that have worked in said population

Poblacion Naquera and within that show me company1 and company2

I hope I explained myself better

This is my Json

```
{
    "resultsObras": [
        {
        "id": "2",
        "empresa": "company 1",
        "latitude": "xxx",
        "longitude": "xx",
        "poblacion": "Naquera",
        "direccion": "Caseta",
        "obra": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "empresa": "company 2",
        "latitude": "xxx",
        "longitude": "xxx",
        "poblacion": "Naquera",
        "direccion": "Pl. Padre Manuel Navarro",
        "obra": "Colector"
    }
       
    ]
}
```

and this is the adapter

```
class ObrasAdapter(val obras : List<ResultsObras>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ObrasAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
obras
    private lateinit var mContext: Context

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent : ViewGroup, viewType : Int) : ViewHolder {
        mContext = parent.context
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

        return ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.obras_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder : ViewHolder, position : Int) {

        val groupCity = obras
            .groupingBy(ResultsObras::empresa)
            .reduce { _, groupState, employee ->
                if (groupState.empresa.isEmpty()) groupState else employee
            }
        groupCity.forEach { (company, state) ->
            holder.itemView.tvPoblacion.text = "${state.poblacion}  $company"
        }

        val item = obras[position]
        holder.bind(item)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { view ->
            val intent = Intent(view.context, MapsActivity::class.java)

            intent.putExtras(Bundle().apply {
                putParcelable("OBRAS", item)
            })
            view.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() : Int {
        return obras.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        private val binding = ObrasItemBinding.bind(view)

        fun bind(clientes : ResultsObras) {
            //println("OBRAS conjunto1 " + conjunto1)

//            binding.tvPoblacion.text = clientes.toString()
//            binding.tvEmpresa.text = clientes.empresa
//            binding.tvObra.text = clientes.direccion
//            binding.tvCometario.text = clientes.obra
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question asks about ‘companies’ and ‘populations’ and ‘state’, but the identifiers in the code are mostly in another language, so the goal isn't clear (to those of us who don't understand that language). Also, the code is missing the definition of `ResultsObras` (but includes quite a bit of code that looks irrelevant); could you could create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Your description about end result isn't very clear. I can't tell what you want to group, and what each row of your RecyclerView should represent (a sub list? a single item already in a group from the main list?) You definitely shouldn't be using a group operation on the main list (`obras` I think) in `onBindViewHolder()`, since `onBindViewHolder()` is called once for every individual item when it scrolls onto the screen. If you want to modify your main list, you should do it once outside the Adapter class before passing it to the adapter.

Comment: post edited with the json